# Which analytics services/frameworks/sdk can be used in Windows Phone background agents?

Tags: google-analytics, windows-phone, flurry, bugsense, yandex-metrika

As most of us know, background agents in Windows Phone have limitations on API (either which can be used or referenced).

What I'm looking for is a framework or service or SDK that allows to track events/crashes/logs from background agents.

List of services known:

- https://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/  (see [discussion here](https://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/discussions/448134))

What are you, folks, using for analytics in background agents?

Comment: Good question.  I have exactly the same query.  I have tried using Flurry but it does not appear to be working - certainly seeing nothing  appearing from the background agent in analytics.

Comment: @Alex did you got any better Analytics tool? Please let me know if you have got a tool as mentioned in my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255229/which-is-the-best-analytics-and-error-logging-tool-in-windows-phone-8

Comment: Nothing that will be 100% satisfying your needs, @BalrajSingh. In my situation we ended with custom analytics using our own API calls (we made the calls already in the agent)

Comment: Thanks Alex. Will try to go for Custom solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Background agents have very low memory limits. That's why in the agent I've used my own custom code that only saves some data to the isolated storage.

Later, when my app is launched normally in the foreground, I read and handle that data. For example if my background agent has crashed I notify user "audio has been terminated due to an error: ..." and submit a crash report.